# Effective way of measuring method execution time

Tags: .net, profiling

I have a .net video processing application, that, when given a large streaming image sequence (a video) is sometimes not delivering a real time frame rate on the output. The processing steps include executing several methods on an incoming frame. What is an effective way (maybe a ready to use library) in .net to profile method execution? (know exactly which method took how much time to see at what step we have a jams)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927/what-are-some-good-net-profilers.

Comment: Not to be a guesser, but are your methods new-ing things? That could be a killer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, using a profiler. Try Equatec, ANTS or dotTrace.

If you just some quick and dirty output, the [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class gives you high-res timing stats. Just new one up, start and stop and check the Elapsed property.