# track the execution time of a method in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, performance

Hi is there any tool to find out the execution time of a method?

Because my application (asp.net web application) is running very slowly and I want to find out the method which is taking more time to respond or execute.

Thanks in advance
jestges

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the Stopwatch class

```
Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
sw.Stop();
```

Comment: My application is having many pages. I dont think I can put this class in each and every method. Actually I'm looking for a tool which will read all my methods and provide me the response times. So that I can fine tune those methods in order to improve performance. Hope you understand

Answer (score 1):

You need to use profiler which will show the execution time.
Refer to [Effective way of measuring method execution time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692001/effective-way-of-measuring-method-execution-time) for various option.